# Is there a mistake in Android official documentation regarding "flags" parameter of the registerReceiver method in the ContextCompat class?

Tags: android

I have created a dynamic broadcast receiver that receives notifications from the Android operating system when battery percentage of the phone changes. Everything works fine, but I don't understand why my broadcast receiver receives those notifications even when `receiverFlags` is set to `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`. This confuses me since official Android documentation says the following about `flags` parameter of the `registerReceiver` method:

> If this receiver is listening for broadcasts sent from the system or from other apps—even other apps that you own—use the RECEIVER_EXPORTED flag. If instead this receiver is listening only for broadcasts sent by your app, use the RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag.

So, I believe that if i set the `flags` parameter to `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`, my broadcast receiver shouldn't receive broadcasts from the Android operating system since the documentation clearly says that my receiver in this case will only listen for broadcasts sent within my app, excluding those from other apps or from the operating system.

I am convinced that this is a mistake in the documentation, but correct me if I am wrong.

Below is my code snippet:

```
class BRMainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

private var br: BroadcastReceiver? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val br = ReceiverForExternalBroadcasts()
    val filter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
    val listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps = false
    val receiverFlags = if (listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps) {
        ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
    } else {
        ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    }
    ContextCompat.registerReceiver(this, br, filter, receiverFlags)

    setContent {
        MainActivityContent()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    unregisterReceiver(br)
}
```

}

Comment: "I am convinced that this is a mistake in the documentation" -- I suspect that you are correct. System broadcasts do not require the receiver to be exported in all cases. This floored me when I first encountered it.